# Смысл слова "образ"

Tags: значение-слов

Точнее, более интересно использование данного корня в формировании слов: *образование* (получить образование), *образованный* (грамотный).

Да и, собственно, образование слова *образ* моими глазами: *об-раз* -- два в одном. 
Ваши мысли, господа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не только Вашими глазами, и глазами Фасмера тоже:

Образ - От оb- и rаzъ, связанного чередованием с rězati; см. раз, ре́зать. Отсюда образова́ть, образо́ванный; образова́ние.

А вот Цыганенко трактует:

В др.-рус. языке образъ означало «вид, образ, призрак, изображение, икона, пример, способ». Др.-рус. образъ восходит к праслав. *оbrаzъ. Слово образ первонач. значило «удар», «след удара» > «то, что вырезано, выбито», затем «нарисованное, вид, форма», «облик», собств. «то, что врезалось в память», «худож. представление».
От сущ. образъ «изображение, вид» произведены:

- с суф. -ьц-ь уменьш. образьць «бляха, украшение», после утраты слаб. ь и прояснения ь > ев сильной позиции — соврем. образец «форма изготовления чего-либо», «примерный (показательный) экземпляр чего-либо»;
- с суф. -ова-ти (как пировать) создан глаг. образовати — ст.-сл. «благословить образом, иконой» (устар.), др.-рус. «составить что-либо», «указывать» > соврем. образовать «придать соответствующую форму, составить что-либо».

От глаг. образовати «составить» с пом. суф. -aниj-e (как собрание) произведено сущ.образование1 «действие по этому глаг.»

От образовати «указывать» > «направлять» >«обучать» произведено сущ. образование2 «процесс усвоения знаний», «просвещение» (в памятниках отмечается с XVI в.)

Так что всё логично: от образа как впечатления(то, что врезалось в память)к глаголу образовать - составить мнение по впечатлениям, от него  значение - дать образование, т.е. помочь составить мнение по впечатлениям как отдельное знание, обучить. Вот и свелось к обучению.

Понятно и почему "образ" в ст.-слав. - икона, лик - нарисованное изображение. Но это уже омоним.

Comment: Людмила, Вас снова правили, и хотя правка была совершенно безобидной, я откатил на Ваш вариант, зная, что Вам подобное доставляет дискомфорт.

Comment: Спасибо, хотя дискомфорт доставляет     мне только ситуация,когда "портят"   ответ, а если что-то там с внешним видом - ради бога, если кого-то раздражают мелочи.

Comment: Так в том-то вся и беда, что понятия "портят" у каждого своё. По мне так все портит, что не улучшает. А улучшает только исправление ***очевидных*** опечаток и недоразумений форматирования. Остальное автор сам вправе сделать . Ну как скажете.